# How do i ensure that tail would read file even it's rotated?

Tags: apache-kafka, tail, logrotate

I'm trying to implement nginx log rotation with sending all logs to [Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org) pubsub messaging. While having a quite large input (about 1GBpm) i'm not sure how tail would behave when log file is rotated.

For example:

1. I'm tailing log file with this command: `tail -F access.log | kafkacat -b broker -t topic`
2. At some point in time `tail` would be locked from reading file due pipe max buffer size, since sending sending messages to kafka not instant.
3. If file would be rotated by `logrotate` command when `tail` is locked, there is no way to tell if previous `access.log` is completely read or there some loglines left.

So here is my question: how do i implement `tail` to `kafkacat` while ensuring that tail will read all file no matter it would or would not been rotated?

Comment: `tail -F` is supposed to handle rotation. Presumably when a file has been renamed it still ensures it fully reads the previous file descriptor.

Comment: @Imm, sadly no. I've tried to move file while pipping it with `tail -F` and it instantly switches to another file descriptor.